# Undefined reference to '_setargv'

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I am new to opencv. While building the basic code, I am getting this error:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat image;// new blank image
image = cv::imread("test.png", 0);// read the file
namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image );// show our image inside it.
waitKey(0);// wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
}
```

Error: c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1......\crt2.0 --- ***Undefined reference to '_setargv'***

Please help me.

Comment: You probably do not have your libraries path set to the appropriate location. Check your compiler settings, and make sure that it is referencing the MinGW object files.

Comment: Checked, can you please pinpoint, if I am wrong.